# Mixed Content is not allowed

Tags: apache-flex

I am trying to restrict a date field in order to be selectable from current date on. For that task I have done this:

```
<ada:AdaFormItem label="{locales.getLabel('form.durationStartDateLong')}"
                 width="100%"
                 labelWidth="130"
                 height="{FormConstants.FORMITEM_HEIGHT}">
    <components:AdaDateField id="inDurationStartDate"
                             selectableRange="{{rangeStart:new Date()}}" />
                             restrict="{FormConstants.DATE_CHARS}"/>
</ada:AdaFormItem>
```

However in the line where  `selectableRange="{{rangeStart:new Date()}}" />`  is it says the following error: "Mixed Content is not allowed"

What is the reasong of this problem?

Comment: There is one wrong `/>` before the `restrict` attribute in your example. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: You are mixing namespaces. Is AdaDatefield in components?